# A can complete a project in 20 days and B can complete the same project in 30 days.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A can complete a project in 20 days and B can complete the same project in 30 days. If A and B start working on the project together and A quits 10 days before the project is completed, in how many days will the project be completed?

Comment: That's assuming they can work concurrently. [Nine women can't make a baby in one month](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks's_law)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1$ day work of $A,B$ is $1/20,1/30$ of the total work respectively.

Let no. of days required be $x$, then Work done by $A=(1/20)(x-10)$ and work done by $B=(1/30)x$

Total of their work is $1$ which gives the equation $$\frac{x-10}{20}+\frac{x}{30}=1$$

Now, solve for $x$